# Move wordpress installation from subdomain to root and keep links

Tags: wordpress, seo, redirect

ok this is bit weird question:
here is my domain: hfarazm.com
and wordpress installation at: blog.hfarazm.com

I have lots of visitors and they have shared my blog and article links all over.

I want to organize my site for separate section for tutorials, for blog, for portfolio and for other things.

Right now everything is going to blog.hfarazm.com i want to move blog to root but want to keep links so that users dont see 404 page and i get a chance to manage my site from the root.

I know: changing url in settings of wordpress will do the job but is redirecting is good practice? what is the better solution to achieve this confusing state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `.htaccess` rules so your visitors will be redirected to new location, even if they type the URL `blog.hfarazm.com`.

See detailed information [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html).

Note that many of these examples won't work unchanged in your particular server configuration, so it's important that you understand them, rather than merely cutting and pasting the examples into your configuration.